# What is the differece between Shell and ShellStream in SSH.NET?

Tags: .net, ssh, ssh.net

And when should I use `Shell` vs `ShellStream`?

My intent is to send keys one by one (if possible, sending Ctrl-like keys separate from the alphanumeric keys), not the whole commands, and receive the terminal's virtual screen updates in real time as the server pushes them (which I expect to be of fixed dimensions, e.g. 80x32).

Answer (score 0):

It's just a different API to the same functionality.

Use the one that suits you better.

---

In general, avoid trying to automate interactive graphical shell commands, unless you have no better API.